# How can I copy a string variable to another character by character without defining size of target variable?

Tags: c++, string

I was writing a program where I need to copy a string (length unknown initially) to another string character by character.

I write this code that runs perfectly.

```
string a = "Hello";
string b( a.length(), 'a');
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    b[i] = a[i];
```

But as the size of the string in C++ is calculated dynamically as

```
string k = "Hello";
string l = "Hello World";
string m = k;
m = l;
```

won't give any error. So it is clear that size of a string variable is changing dynamically according to the requirement.

So I tried the same without defining the size of the variable `b`.

```
string a = "Hello";
string b;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    b[i] = a[i];
```

But in this case, my program is crashing and saying **String subscript out of range**.

Why not in this case the size of variable `b` is increasing?
What is the cause of the error and how can I achieve this without mentioning the size of any variable?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  `std::string` has an `operator=` and you can just use `b = a` and now `b` is a copy of `a`.

Comment: This just might be the ultimate X/Y question.

Comment: Well, I'm writing a program that decrypts a given text by copying the text 3 position right. So I have to traverse the whole plain text and copy the 3 character next of the current character.

Comment: No still not @TreytenCarey

Comment: @Siraj Like `Hello` will become `lloHe`?

Comment: No, 3rd next character of `h` is `k` so
`Hello` will become `khoor`

Comment: What about instead of `b[i] = a[i];` you tried `b.append(a.begin()+i, a.begin()+i+1);`

Comment: You try to impelement a caesar chiffre?

Comment: @Siraj In that case you should copy if you need the original (`b = a`) and then use [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) to move all the elements over

Comment: Yes, @manni66. And the key is not fixed to 3, it is received in the argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you must, you can use `push_back`:

```
string a = "Hello";
string b;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    b.push_back(a[i]);
```

or even<sup>1</sup>

```
string a = "Hello";
string b;
for (auto c : a)
    b.push_back(c);
```

But why?

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back

---

<sup>1</sup> But don't do this if `a` is changed in any way: the underlying iterators will be invalidated.

Comment: Well, I'm writing a program that decrypts a given text by copying the text 3 position right. So I have to traverse the whole plain text and copy the 3 character next of the current character.

Comment: Why it is crashing in the second case if the size is calculated dynamically?

Comment: @Siraj: Yes the second way will crash if `a` is changed due to iterator invalidation.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `+=` operator:

```
for (auto el : a){
    b += el;
}
```

The [std::string::operator+=](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) has an overload that accepts character.

Comment: Note this is vulnerable to changes in `a` invalidating the underlying iterators.

Comment: I didn't know about overloaded `+=` operator. Thanks @Ron

Answer (score 0):

Size of the string is dynamic, but it not changed automaticaly as you expect. operator[] only return i-th element, if current size of a string is less than i, it fill fail. It's up to you to make sure size of a string is big enough.

If you couldn't resize string in advance you can query size, increase it by one, ask string to resize, and set last char.

This is how [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) method works

Comment: _"if current size of a string is less than i, it fill fail"_ No - it'll invoke undefined behaviour, which is **much worse** than just 'failing'. If you want to check whether the bound if valid and *not silently explode* if it isn't, there's `.at()` for that.